# How do you get a cart for a specific user using the Magento Core API?

Tags: php, magento, drupal, drupal-7

I'm trying to show a cart icon in Drupal with the number of items in the cart of our sister Magento site.

I'm using the [Magento Core API](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/doc/webservices-api/api/cart#cart.info) to look up information on customers and use it in Drupal. I'm trying to load the contents of the cart for a specific Magento Customer ID, but I don't see any way to do this. The cart info API method only supports look ups by quote ID. Quote ID appears to be the primary key for a cart.

Is it possible to look up cart information by customer ID with a Magento API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't fetch this information using the Magento Core API, or even the new REST Api. If you wanted this information you'd need to write your own Magento extension and have it installed on the system you're targeting.

The "Cart" object in Magento ties a specific user account to a specific Magento "quote" object.  A quote is an order before it's an order object.  In Magento's "PHP API" (i.e. the native PHP objects Magento developers use to manipulate the system), this is a `sales/quote` object.

```
$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote');
```

Data for this object is stored in the the `sales_flat_quote` table, and there is a `customer_id` column so you should be able to get at the information you need.

Comment: is it possible to load quote by id ?

Comment: @mahdi you can load a quote by any criteria.  Look into Magento/Varien data collections.

Comment: but will not show product on frontend. To show product at frontend I have to add product to checkout/cart.

Comment: how to get the all quoteids in .net soap api

Answer (score 0):

The customer.info method does not return the active quote id for the customer according to the documentation, so it doesn't look like you can by default. It's pretty easy to extend the core API with a custom module to provide the quote id though. Or you could extend the checkout module and build a new api method that does the lookup by customer id instead and avoid the customer.info request all together. Have a read of http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/doc/webservices-api/custom-api for a guide on how to do this. Benefit of having a custom API method is that you can optimize it (Maybe do a query that gives you just the data you want (i.e. Just the number of products for the quote) instead of loading the full quote object).

P.S. Are you making the request for your drupal site by AJAX? I would as the API is slow and you don't want the drupal site hanging for a few seconds whilst you do the lookup.